# Setting custom event listeners

Tags: android, event-handling

I'm trying to set a custom event listener but the flag isn't getting triggered. Here's the relevant code:

```
public interface onPlayerSetUpEventListener {
    public void onPlayerSetUp();
}

private onPlayerSetUpEventListener mOnPlayerSetUpEventListener;

public void setOnPlayerSetUpEventListener(onPlayerSetUpEventListener eventListener) {
    mOnPlayerSetUpEventListener = eventListener;
}

public void playerSetUp() {
    if(mOnPlayerSetUpEventListener != null){
        mOnPlayerSetUpEventListener.onPlayerSetUp();
    }
} 

/* The listener is set here */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initializeHotels();
    FIRST_TURN = true;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    clearOldBoard();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_board);
    setUpBoardGUI();
    setUpPlayers();

    setOnPlayerSetUpEventListener(new onPlayerSetUpEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerSetUp(){
            prepForFirstTurn();
        }
    });

/* playerSetUp() should trigger the event */

public void setUpPlayers(){
    <!-- Here we set up all the players and prep them for the start of game -->
    playerSetUp();
}
```

I'm very new to event handling here so an extra pair of eyes to help me identify what happened and why the event isn't getting executed would be great!

Is it because it's trying to handle the event inside of `onCreate()`?

Thanks for you help in advance!

JRad The Bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `setUpPlayers();` before you set the listener on the next line.